# How to use static scripts with MVC architecture?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have used url re-write with .htaccess.

This is **.htaccess** file content

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Disallows others to look directly into /public/ folder
Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /myMVC/

# General rewrite rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="public/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
</html>
```

**Problem**

I can't see any style associated with boostrap css file.

When i load this url : `http://localhost/myMVC/user` it is working. But when i use this url : `http://localhost/myMVC/user/login` it is not working

File structure

[image]

Another view of file structure 
[image]

Comment: Use this: `<link href="/public/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @anubhava ur way is not working.

Comment: comment out your rule and retest.

Answer (score 1):

Index file is in public folder

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this should work

Comment: No index.php file in root folder (myMVC folder)

Comment: @SurajMalinga where is your index.php file

Comment: It's seems to be in public folder.but, actually it is in root folder. I added another view of file structure..